# Misbehaving QSignals in QThreadPool, QRunnable using QThead on top of it in python

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, qthread

Im stuck in one situation where my first few signals are getting passed and later on no signals are getting emitted.

I'll elaborate it in detail:

I've a job which required heavy processing and ram and can take upto 2-4 hours to complete it without threading in linear way, so I decided to use QTheadPool, so I created (while testing) 355 QRunners which gets started by QThreadPool. And few of them(QRunners) are depends on another QRunners to finish. Its all working fine, I'm able to derive dependencies by emitting signals and catching them. Its all working absolutely perfect when I run this without GUI

For example (below codes are not tested, i just typed here):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class StreamPool(QtCore.QObject):
  def __init__(self, inputs, q_app):
    super(....)

    self.inputs = inputs
    self.q_app = q_app

    self.pool = QtCore.QThreadPool()

  def start(self):
    for each_input in self.inputs:
      runner = StreamRunner(each_input, self.q_app)
      runner.signal.operation_started.connect(self.mark_as_start)
      runner.signal.operation_finished.connect(self.mark_as_start)
      self.pool.start(runner)

  def mark_as_start(self, name):
    print 'operation started..', name
    # Some operation...

  def mark_as_finish(self, name):
    print 'operation finished..', name
    # Some operation...

class StreamRunner(QtCore.QRunnable):
  def __init__(self, input, q_app):
    super(..)

    self.input = input            
    self.q_app = q_app
    self.signal = WorkSignals()


  def run(self):
    self.signal.operation_started.emit(input)
    self.q_ap

    # Doing some operations

    self.signal.operation_finished.emit(input)
    self.q_app.processEvents()    

class WorkSignals(QtCore.QObject):
  operation_started = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
  operation_finished= QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)



if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QtGui.QApplication([])      
  st = StreamPool(['a', 'b', 'c'], app)
  st.start()
  app.exec_()
```

It works brilliant in above case.

And I want to show the statuses in ui as there can be hundreds of task can be executed, so I wrote a simple ui, and running StreamPool() from another QThread lets say named - StreamWorkThread() which is getting spawned by ui, and StreamWorkThread catching StreamPool.signal.* and sending them back to ui, but in this case StreamPool can only emit few of them, the starting 4 or 5, though the tasks are still getting executed but the dependent task are not getting initialized due to this behavior and no status updates are getting displayed in ui.

I cant share the code with you guys, as its from my work place, I can write similar approach here

```
class StreamWorkThread (QtCore.QThread):
  def __init__(self, inputs, q_app):
    super(..)

    self.signal = WorkSignals()
    self.stream_pool = StreamPool(inputs, q_app)self.stream_pool.signal.operation_started.connect(self.signal.operation_started.emit)
    self.stream_pool.signal.operation_finished.connect(self.signal.operation_finished.emit)

  def run(self):
    self.stream_pool.start()


def print_start(name):
  print 'Started --', name

def print_finished(name):
  print 'Finished --', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QtGui.QApplication([])      
  th = StreamWorkThread (['a', 'b', 'c'], app)
  th.signal.operation_started.connect(print_start)
  th.signal.operation_finshed.connect(print_finished)
  th.start()
  app.exec_()
```

Consolidated code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class StreamPool(QtCore.QObject):
  def __inti__(self, inputs, q_app):
    super(StreamPool, self).__init()

    self.inputs = inputs
    self.q_app = q_app

    self.pool = QtCore.QThreadPool()

  def start(self):
    for each_input in self.inputs:
      runner = StreamRunner(each_input, self.q_app)
      runner.signal.operation_started.connect(self.mark_as_start)
      runner.signal.operation_finished.connect(self.mark_as_start)
      self.pool.start(runner)

  def mark_as_start(self, name):
    print 'operation started..', name
    # Some operation...

  def mark_as_finish(self, name):
    print 'operation finished..', name
    # Some operation...

class StreamRunner(QtCore.QRunnable):
  def __init__(self, input, q_app):
    super(StreamRunner, self).__init()

    self.input = input            
    self.q_app = q_app
    self.signal = WorkSignals()


  def run(self):
    self.signal.operation_started.emit(input)
    self.q_ap

    # Doing some operations

    self.signal.operation_finished.emit(input)
    self.q_app.processEvents()    

class WorkSignals(QtCore.QObject):
  operation_started = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
  operation_finished= QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

class StreamWorkThread (QtCore.QThread):
  def __init__(self, inputs, q_app):
    super(StreamWorkThread, self).__init()

    self.signal = WorkSignals()
    self.stream_pool = StreamPool(inputs,q_app)
    self.stream_pool.signal.operation_started.connect(self.signal.operation_started.emit)
    self.stream_pool.signal.operation_finished.connect(self.signal.operation_finished.emit)

  def run(self):
    self.stream_pool.start()


def print_start(name):
  print 'Started --', name

def print_finished(name):
  print 'Finished --', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QtGui.QApplication([])      
  th = StreamWorkThread (['a', 'b', 'c'], app)
  th.signal.operation_started.connect(print_start)
  th.signal.operation_finshed.connect(print_finished)
  th.start()
  app.exec_()
```

Please guys help me, im not getting what exactly the problem here..! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got the solution for this behavior.

The root cause of blocking the signal is inheriting `QObject` in StrealPool, when I replace QObject with `QThread` it worked seamlessly.

Here are the changes I made, only tow places

```
class StreamPool(**QtCore.QThread**):
  def __inti__(self, inputs, q_app):
    super(StreamPool, self).__init()

    self.inputs = inputs
    self.q_app = q_app

    self.pool = QtCore.QThreadPool()

  def **run**(self):
    for each_input in self.inputs:
      runner = StreamRunner(each_input, self.q_app)
      runner.signal.operation_started.connect(self.mark_as_start)
      runner.signal.operation_finished.connect(self.mark_as_start)
      self.pool.start(runner)
```

and that set, it worked ! :D

Answer (score 0):

very difficult without the source code, but the problem is probably when "app.exec_()" is run, the mainloop of the gui is started and interferes with your Streamx classes

Comment: thanks for the quick response @Ludovic, but here even if I didnt invoke ui and just invoke StreamWorkThread it wont work. Though first few signals gets emitted. Is there any another approach you suggest?

Comment: One more thing I would like to point out if I add self.pool.waitForDone() at the end of the StreamPool().start() method, Im able to receive all the signals but at the very end of the operations, at the end, this way my ui wont be having real time status updates all the statuses will update at once

Comment: try to override the default destructor of StreamWorkThread (method named `__del__`) and print something for see if it is garbage collected, you can also execute self.wait() in the destructor

Comment: tried overriding `__del__` added print statement and `self.wait()` even if I use `waitForDone()` or not its not hitting `__del__`.

Comment: what is QRunner ? is it QRunnable ? Did you try the threading module from the standard lib ?

Comment: ohh my mistake its `QRunnable`, no havent tried the builtin lib

Comment: ahah !!! perhaps it s stupid but your class WorkSignals make use of "class" attribute, so if you redefine them in an instance, it can invalidate other instances ...

Comment: in that case it should emit some signals atleast till end, though I'll try putting under other class name